# Xamarin.Forms accessibility on layouts

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, talkback

I'm making an app for blind people using Xamarin.Forms (Portable). I can easily set talkback content for buttons, entries, etc. with effects. But things like StackLayouts have no controls so effects do not attach to them. Either way, Android Talkback still picks them up and reads them. How can I make layouts invisible to Talkback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the ImportantForAccessibility property.  You likely want to set it to ImportantForAccessibility.NoHideDescendants.  I don't know much about Xamarin, or I would post a code example!

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.ImportantForAccessibility/